# Idiomatic C++11 for delegating template specialisations to a default implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm making a struct `Box<T>` that handles some data. The specifics are unimportant.
An important note however is that `Box<T>` can store a pointer, but it might not. So both `Box<int>` and `Box<int *>` are valid. Obviously, if we own `Box.data`, we're going to need to `delete` data if it is a pointer type.
Here's a solution I came up with that works in C++11:

```cpp
template <typename T> struct BoxTraits;

template <typename T> struct Box {
    using traits_t = BoxTraits<T>;

    T data;

    ~Box() = default; // not required, I know

    T get_data() { return traits_t::get_data(this); }
};

template <typename T> struct Box<T *> {
    using traits_t = BoxTraits<T *>;

    T *data;

    ~Box() { delete data; }

    T *get_data() { return traits_t::get_data(this); }
};

template <typename T> struct BoxTraits {
    static T get_data(Box<T> *const box) { return box->data; }
};
```

`Box::get_data` is here to illustrate an issue with this design pattern. For every single method I want to add to `Box`, I need to add some boiler plate in each specialisation. Note that I would also need a `Box<T *const>` specialisation.

This seems like quite a rubbish solution. In C++14, I could use `if constexpr` with a `is_ptr<T>` trait and only have to write extra code in the methods that need specialising... Is there any way I can do this is in C++11?

This solution is shorter, cleaner *and* works for `Box<U *const>`!

```cpp
template <typename T> struct is_ptr { static const bool value = false; };

template <typename U> struct is_ptr<U *> { static const bool value = true; };

template <typename U> struct is_ptr<U *const> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename T> struct Box {
    T data;

    ~Box() {
        if constexpr (is_ptr<T>::value) {
            delete data;
        }
    }

    T get_data() { return data; }
};
```

Comment: I don't have much sense of what kind of methods you want to add to this. Can they all just call `get_data` or do they also need to be somehow different for pointers? If the second version lets them behave naturally with `U * const data`, what are the traits doing for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, C++11 already has [std::is_pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer), no need to roll your own. You can see that it inherits from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` instead of defining its own `value` member. The reason for that is tag dispatching, that can effectively replace `if constexpr` in this situation:

```
template <typename T> struct Box {
    T data;

    ~Box() {
        destroy(std::is_pointer<T>{});
    }

private:
    void destroy(std::true_type) {
        delete data;
    }
    void destroy(std::false_type) {} // nothing to do
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rcPdfx69d)

I think this is the most idiomatic way in C++11 for delegating to different implementations based on type traits. In many situations, tag dispatching can replace `if constexpr` (from C++17, not C++14), and I believe the latter always replaces the former in addition to being clearer. Tag dispatching can also be used before C++11 if you roll your own type traits.

Last note: you don't *need* to use the standard type traits, you can do something like this:

```
template <typename T> struct is_ptr { static const bool value = false; };
template <typename T> struct is_ptr<T*> { static const bool value = true; };
template <typename T> struct is_ptr<T* const> { static const bool value = true; };
template <typename T> struct is_ptr<T* volatile> { static const bool value = true; };
template <typename T> struct is_ptr<T* const volatile> { static const bool value = true; };

template<bool b>
struct bool_constant {};

template<typename T>
struct Box {
    T data;

    ~Box() {
        destroy(bool_constant<is_ptr<T>::value>{});
    }

private:
    void destroy(bool_constant<true>) {
        delete data;
    }
    void destroy(bool_constant<false>) {} // nothing to do
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3orjffdvT)

However, this pretty much amounts to recreating the standard type traits, but probably worse. Just use the standard library when possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had the right idea with the helper type, but I'd do it like the following example illustrates.

```
template <typename B, typename T>
struct BoxTraits {
    static T& get_data(B *const box) { return box->data; }
        //  ^--- important
    static T const& get_data(B const* const box) { return box->data; }
};
template <typename T>
struct BoxTraits<Box<T*>, T> {
    static T& get_data(Box<T*>* const box) { return *box->data; }
    static T const& get_data(Box<T*> const* const box) { return *box->data; }
};
```

Both versions always return `T`, so you can use them the same regardless of your Box's payload. You could add a type alias in Box so you don't have to pass the template arguments:

```
typedef Traits BoxTraits<Box, T>; // in Box class
```